# Diophantine: $a^n + b^n + c^n = d^n$ and $a^n + b^n = c^n + d^n$

Tags: diophantine-equations, nt.number-theory

Let us consider the equation $a^n+b^n=c^n$ for positive integers $a,b,c$ and $n\ge 2$. The $n=2$ case has a well-known and beautiful parametrization known as Pythagorean triples. Fermat's Last Theorem gives us that there are no solutions for $n\ge 3$.

It can be observed from the literature that Diophantine equations involving a sum of individual variables to some like power, i.e. $a_1^n+\cdots+a_k^n=b_1^n+\cdots+b_m^n$, are considered to be among the most "attractive" of problems.

Maybe with more controversy, it can be said that constructing (a family of) solutions is easier with a greater number of terms, thanks to the added flexibility. In this sense, Fermat's question of splitting a power into two same powers in the "tightest" question.

This brings us to the next tightest equations, which add one more term: For which $n\ge 2$ do $a^n + b^n + c^n = d^n$ or $a^n + b^n = c^n + d^n$ (call them $(1)$ and $(2)$ respectively) have solutions in positive **integers**, what are some solutions, and can we find all of them? We are looking at non-trivial solutions, so in $(2)$, $a,b$ are distinct from $c,d$.

Of course, families or full parametrizations represented by polynomials are the prettiest. I read somewhere that full ones exist for $n=2$ in each case, but **a reference would be nice**.

Now $n\ge 3$ is a murky area, as far as I can tell. One famous result is Elkies' counterexamples to Euler's quartic conjecture, so $(1)$ has infinitely many solutions for $n=4$. The Mathworld pages on [3rd powers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiophantineEquation3rdPowers.html) and [4th powers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiophantineEquation4thPowers.html) say that families of solutions to $(1)$ are known for $n=3$, as well as for $(2)$ for $n=3,4$.

At this point, for larger $n$, there seem to be no known solutions to either equations; correct me otherwise please. So my question is:

**What are references to results on larger $n$ for these two equations? Has it been proven that no integer solutions exist for some, probably large, $n$? Maybe even all sufficiently large $n$?**

Comment: The non-existence of solutions for $n$ large is an open problem. It's known that the corresponding surfaces contain only finitely many rational or elliptic curves for $n$ large  ($\ge 16$?), so if you believe the Bombieri-Lang conjecture...

Comment: 
Actually under Bombieri-Lang the number is already finite for $n \geq 5$,
because that's when the surface is of general type.  It is known
unconditionally (via the Wronskian trick) that there are no nontrivial
rational curves for $n \geq 8$, nor any elliptic curves for $n \geq 9$.
There's a nontrivial rational curve for $n=5$ (residual conic on the
intersection of $a^5+b^5+c^5+d^5=0$ with $a+b+c+d=0$), but unfortunately
it has no rational or even real points.  For $n=6$ there's an elliptic curve
that yields infinitely many rational points on some twists such as
$a^6+2b^6+125c^6=2d^6$.

Comment: For the side questions: for references for classical results you mention, the Survey of equal sums of like powers by Lander, Parkin, Selfridge could be of interest to you, see  http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0025-5718-1967-0222008-0 (it is free)  Also for lists of solutions, in cases where they exist, for these types of equations (more variables) http://www.maa.org/editorial/mathgames/mathgames_11_13_06.html  is a nice starting point linking to other resources such as the EulerNet http://euler.free.fr/ a distributed computing effort. 

Comment: NB When I commented "the number is already finite" I meant the number of
rational or elliptic *curves* other than the obvious lines such as the line
$a=c,b=d$ on $a^n+b^n = c^n+d^n$.
If that number is zero (as is known to be the case for $n \geq 9$),
*then* the same conjecture implies that the number of nontrivial
rational solutions is finite too.  The expectation is that there are
no nontrivial rational solutions for either equation once $n \geq 5$.

Comment: You can have a quick overview of known solvable cases in this related [MO answer](http://mathoverflow.net/a/191939/12905).

Answer (score 2):

It is a folklore conjecture that for $n \geq 5$ that for any positive integer $k$ there are at most two pairs of positive integers such that $x^n + y^n = k$ for $n \geq 5$, and they are related by the obvious symmetry of swapping $x,y$. See for example [this paper](https://www.degruyter.com/view/journals/crll/1995/462/article-p57.xml) by Skinner and Wooley.

The state of the art regarding this matter is to investigate how dense off-diagonal solutions to the equation $x^n + y^n = u^n + v^n$ is. As far as I know this was done in general by [Bennett, Dummigan, and Wooley in 1998](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/compositio-mathematica/article/representation-of-integers-by-binary-additive-forms/0BF56477B34FEA569AF64A3A05AEEC84). My self and Cam Stewart obtained the more general result concerning $F(x,y) = F(u,v)$ for general binary forms of degree $d \geq 3$ in [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00208-019-01855-y).