# On Choudhry's $x_1^k+x_2^k+x_3^k+x_4^k = y_1^k+y_2^k+y_3^k+y_4^k$ for $k=7$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, diophantine-equations

**I. Fifth Powers**

The Diophantine equation,

$$x_1^k+x_2^k+x_3^k = y_1^k+y_2^k+y_3^k\tag1$$

for $k=5$ is quite well-explored. It has an infinite number of **primitive** solutions (as points on an *elliptic curve*, or an infinite family of polynomials). They can be simultaneously true for $k=1,5$ and in [a 2013 paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/44240281), Choudhry and Wroblewki found an infinite subset that satisfy the side condition,

$$\sum\limits^3 x_i = \sum\limits^3 y_i = 0$$

---

**II. Seventh Powers**

Since the first solution  to,

$$x_1^k+x_2^k+x_3^k+x_4^k = y_1^k+y_2^k+y_3^k+y_4^k\tag2$$

for $k=7$ was found almost 30 years ago by Randy Ekl in 1996, only $113$ primitive solutions (in positive and negative integers) have been found so far. In [a 2000 paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/44238512), Choudhry found solutions **simultaneously** true for $k = 1,3,7$ and satisfy the analogous side condition,

$$\sum\limits^4 x_i = \sum\limits^4 y_i = 0$$

Wrobrewski would later find more solutions, for a total of 24. They used the form,

$$(X_1-X_2-X_3)^k+(-X_1+X_2-X_3)^k+(-X_1-X_2+X_3)^k+(X_1+X_2+X_3)^k = (Y_1-Y_2-Y_3)^k+(-Y_1+Y_2-Y_3)^k+(-Y_1-Y_2+Y_3)^k+(Y_1+Y_2+Y_3)^k$$

which is identically true for $k=1$ and is true for $k=3,7$ if the two conditions,

$$X_1X_2X_3=Y_1Y_2Y_3$$
$$2(X_1^4 + X_2^4 + X_3^4) - 5(X_1^2 + X_2^2 + X_3^2)^2= 2(Y_1^4 + Y_2^4 + Y_3^4) - 5(Y_1^2 + Y_2^2 + Y_3^2)^2$$

are met. Using the $x_i,y_i$ (see [euler.free.fr](http://euler.free.fr/database.txt)), I derived their $X_i, Y_i$. Surprisingly, seven had a simple linear constraint, namely $X_3=2Y_3$. Let,

$$X_1,\,X_2,\,X_3 =u_1 u_2,\;u_3 u_4,\;2u_5$$
$$Y_1,\,Y_2,\,Y_3 =2u_1 u_4,\;u_2 u_3,\;u_5$$

then solutions are,

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\text{#}&u_1&u_2&u_3&u_4&u_5\\
1&127 &139 &313 &1 &23647\\
2&227 &27 &113 &13 &1305\\
3&14737 &139 &15899 &25 &544069 \\
4&303 &304 &338 &37 &24616\\
5&431 &187 &365 &49 &6929\\
6&871 &163 &4364 &127 &254405 \\
7&439 &2459 &247 &1175 &261851 \\
\end{array}$$

Looking at $u_4$, it is tempting to speculate there is a pattern in the $u_i$ and that there are infinitely many $u_i$.

---

**Question:**

1. The first condition $X_1X_2X_3=Y_1Y_2Y_3$ is easily met via the $u_i$. After doing so, can the quartic second condition be split as an intersection of two quadric surfaces [as Elkies did](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/509526/) for $x_1^4+x_2^4+x_3^4= 1,$ or [as Bremner and Ulas did](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4633598/4781) for $x_1^6+x_2^6+x_3^6= y^2$?

**P.S.** Eq.1 is briefly discussed in this [MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/150428/).

Comment: This does not answer your questions, but upon reading the paper, I came across one minute detail. In the first solution mentioned, where $X_1 = 324, X_2 = 5439, X_3 = 893$, what is the "suitable transposition" involved? The $X_i$'s mentioned does not imply $x_1 = 1741$ without that transposition.

Comment: @JesperPetersen: These solutions have the special property  that $\sum_i^4 x_i = \sum_j^4 y_j = 0$. Thus, some of terms are necessarily **negative**. For aesthetics, Choudhry transposed negative terms to the other side of the equation, so labelling is not rigid.  For example, $X_1+X_2+X_3=324+5439+893=2\cdot3328$ where one assumes $y_4 = 3328$. But $-3328$ is really one of the $x_i$ transposed to the other side.

Comment: So if I get it right, does that mean that all solutions of Choudhry always have certain terms with equal sums, as e.g. $ 1741+ 3476= 1937+ 3280$ and $2435
+ 3004
= 2111
+ 3328$ in the first example? Which means he has added a heavy constraint. So he has not exactly "reduced" the original equation (2) [if true for k=1, 3, 7] to (3), but could we rather say: he was lucky that his additional constraint made a computer search more efficient, which allowed him to find a bunch of solutions?

Comment: @Wolfgang: Yes, you are correct. I did not phrase it correctly. There are four constraints: that $k=1,3,7$ and 4th, $\sum\limits^4 x_i = \sum\limits^4 y_i = 0$. There in fact is a solution to $k=1,3,7$, namely $$u_i = 184, 443, 556, 698, -230, -353, -625, -673$$ found by Nuutti Kuosa in 1999 (before Choudhry's paper) that does not have the 4th constraint, namely there is **no** partition such that $\sum\limits^4 u_i = 0$. (I had checked it before.)

Comment: You mean $x_i$ & $y_i$ (and up to sign), not $u_i$ ?

Comment: @Wolfgang: The thing with odd powers is it is better to move them all to one side. Thus I prefer $\sum\limits^8 u_i^k = 0$ versus $\sum\limits^4 x_i^k = \sum\limits^4 y_i^k$. The latter can be mis-leading. For example, one of the seven in the table actually is a $\sum\limits^3 x_i^k = \sum\limits^5 y_i^k$ in positive terms.

Comment: Yes, I figured that. The problem was just that those $u_i$ are different from the $u_1,...,u_4$ in your question :) Interesting that there is just one of type (7,3,5).

Comment: Oh, those $u_i$ are different. I keep gravitating to the same variables. My bad. :) **P.S** There are several (7.3.5) found by Wroblewski using Choudhry's cubic, but the others don't have the "accidental" constraint that $c=2f$.

Comment: @Wolfgang: I updated the post with more details. See Questions.