# How did Ramanujan discover this identity?

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, ramanujan

Let $$\small F_n=(a+b+c)^n+(b+c+d)^n-(c+d+a)^n-(d+a+b)^n+(a-d)^n-(b-c)^n$$ and
$ad=bc$, then
$$64 F_6 F_{10}=45 F_8^2$$
This fascinating identity is due to Ramanujan and can be found in ["Ramanujan for Lowbrows", by B.C. Berndt and S. Bhargava](http://www.maa.org/programs/maa-awards/writing-awards/ramanujan-for-lowbrows). Would anyone have any idea how Ramanujan discovered this identity?

The proofs of the identity offered so far in the papers ["A Note on an Identity of Ramanujan", by T. S. Nanjundiah](http://www.jstor.org/discover/2324305), ["Two or Three Identities of Ramanujan", by M.D. Hirschhorn](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2589526) and ["A remarkable identity found in Ramanujan's third notebook", by B.C. Berndt and S. Bhargava](http://journals.cambridge.org/article_S0017089500008910) make the identity less mysterious, but how Ramanujan found the identity in the first place still remains a mystery. As Berndt and Bhargava remarked, it is also not clear whether this is an accidental, isolated result (along with the 3-7-5 counterpart discovered by Hirschhorn), or if there is  some deeper theorem lurking behind it.

Comment: What's the star operator?

Comment: $*$ is just multiplication.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You have two questions: 1) How Ramanujan discovered it? 2) Is an accidental, isolated result? The second one is easier to answer and may shed light on the first.

> **I.** Define $F_n = x_1^n+x_2^n+x_3^n-(y_1^n+y_2^n+y_3^n),\;$ where $\,\small x_1+x_2+x_3=y_1+y_2+y_3 = 0$.

**Theorem 1:** If $F_1 = F_3 = 0$, then,

$$9x_1x_2x_3 F_6 = 2F_9 = 9y_1y_2y_3 F_6$$

**Theorem 2:** If $F_2 = F_4 = 0$, then,

$$64F_6F_{10} = 45F_8^2\quad \text{(Ramanujan)}$$

$$25F_3F_{7} = 21F_5^2\quad \text{(Hirschhorn)}$$

> **II.** Define $F_n = x_1^n+x_2^n+x_3^n+x_4^n-(y_1^n+y_2^n+y_3^n+y_4^n),\;$ where also $\,\small \sum x_i =\sum y_i= 0$.

**Theorem 3:** If $F_1 = F_3 = F_5 = 0$, then,

$$7F_4F_9 = 12F_6F_7\quad \text{(yours truly)}$$

This also has a similar Ramanujan-type formulation. Define,

$$\small P_n = ((a+b+c)^n + (a-b-c)^n + (-a-b+c)^n + (-a+b-c)^n – ((d+e+f)^n + (d-e-f)^n + (-d-e+f)^n + (-d+e-f)^n)$$

If *two* conditions are satisfied,

$$\small abc = def,\quad a^2+b^2+c^2 = d^2+e^2+f^2$$

then,

$$7P_4P_9 = 12P_6P_7$$

(The two conditions have an infinite number of primitive solutions, one of which is $1,10,12;\,2,4,15$.)

If you are looking for the general theory behind Ramanujan's 6-10-8 Identity, the theorems flow from the properties of ***equal sums of like powers***. The 6-10-8 needed only ***one*** condition, namely $ad=bc$. Going higher, you now need ***two***. Presumably going even higher would need more. Also, there is a constraint  $\,\small \sum x_i =\sum y_i= 0$. Without this constraint, then more generally,

> **III.** Define $F_n = x_1^n+x_2^n+x_3^n-(y_1^n+y_2^n+y_3^n),\;$ and $m = (\sum x_i^4)/(\sum x_i^2)^2$.

**Theorem 4:** If $F_2 = F_4 = 0$, then,

$$32F_6F_{10} = 15(m+1)F_8^2$$

(*Note:* Ramanujan's simply was the case $m=1/2$.)

> **IV.** Define $F_n = x_1^n+x_2^n+x_3^n+x_4^n-(y_1^n+y_2^n+y_3^n+y_4^n),\;$ and $m = (\sum x_i^4)/(\sum x_i^2)^2$.

**Theorem 5:** If $F_2 = F_4 = F_6 = 0$, then,

$$25F_8F_{12} = 12(m+1)F_{10}^2$$

and so on for similar identities with more terms and *multi-grade* higher powers, *ad infinitum*.

**V. Conclusion:** Thus, was the 6-10-8 Identity an isolated result? No, it is a special case (and a particularly beautiful one at that) of a more general phenomenon. And how did Ramanujan find it? Like most of his discoveries, he plucked it out of thin air, I suppose.

**P.S.** Humor aside, what I read was that, as he found paper expensive, he would scribble on a small slateboard with chalk. After he was satisfied with a result, he would write it down on his notebook, and *erase the intermediate steps that was on the slateboard*. (Sigh.)

Also, since he spent most of his waking hours thinking about mathematics, I think it was only natural it spilled over into his dream state. (A similar thing happened with the chemist Kekule and the discovery of the benzene ring.)

**P.P.S.** Results for multi-grades can be found in Table 2 of this [MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/191939/12905).

Comment: This is nice. But in III and IV, what about the $y_i$ in the definition of $m$? Should it be a condition $(\sum x_i^4)/(\sum x_i^2)^2= (\sum y_i^4)/(\sum y_i^2)^2=:m $ ?

Comment: @Wolfgang: No need to define $m$ in terms of $y_i$. If you look at the theorems below them, it assumes $\sum x_i^n = \sum y_i^n$ for $n=2,4$ from which your equality necessarily follows. (For IV, it is $n=2,4,6$.)

Comment: @Tito Very nice! Have you published these results?

Comment: @ZurabSilagadze: Thank you. No, I haven't yet. It is mostly to satisfy my curiosity as I got intrigued by the 6-10-8 identity when I came across it.

Comment: Note that some of these identies are of the form $n^2F_{n-2}F_{n+2}=t_{n+1}F_{n}^{2}$ with $t_m$ the $m$-th triangular number.

Answer (score 10):

One line of [argument](http://www.oocities.org/titus_piezas/RamQuad.pdf) (section II), from a fellow [MO-user,](http://mathoverflow.net/users/12905/tito-piezas-iii) starts from the premise that Ramanujan knew that $F_n=0$ for $n=2$ or $n=4$:

> It’s almost a shame to give away the secret of the 6-10-8 Identity. To
>   quote the poet Keats, it’s like unweaving a rainbow: things will be
>   different once we know something too well.

Comment: Nice article! However, as it states in Conclusions,  "the question remains how he found it in the first  place".

Comment: One possibility is that the identity was communicated to Ramanujan by the Goddess of Namagiri ): . Ramanujan by himself describes one of such dreams (from the book "Tibetan Dream Yoga", by Michael Katz): "While asleep, I had an unusual experience. There was a red screen formed by flowing blood, as it were. I was observing it. Suddenly a hand began to write on the screen. I became all attention. That hand wrote a number of elliptic integrals. They stuck to my mind. As soon as I woke up, I committed them to writing".

Comment: @ZurabSilagadze Yes, that's the obvious answer to how Ramanujan got the identities. But how did the Goddess of Namagiri discover them?

Comment: She did it by plugging in values for the variables.  That, or she consulted an oracle who performed the infinitely many computations.

Comment: @Carlo: I never thought a sentence I wrote ten years ago would find its way here.  :)

Comment: @ZurabSilagadze I up-voted your comment and now I find you've taken it straight off Wikipedia...!

Comment: @JamesSmith I don't remember now, but probably I found it here (I'm not sure about this -- maybe it was indeed Wikipedia):  https://books.google.ru/books?id=hr2ZfC7upmgC&pg=PR37&lpg=PR37&dq=Tibetan+Dream+Yoga+ramanujan&source=bl&ots=LYhSjQUI36&sig=FGxVot-8n8w_En-5Cd9CJR12V5Q&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwihiq2vvPLXAhUjYZoKHZZMAa0Q6AEIOjAH#v=onepage&q=Tibetan%20Dream%20Yoga%20ramanujan&f=false

Comment: @ZurabSilagadze No worries, it's a great find.

Answer (score 6):

(*This is an addendum to my answer*.)

**I. Identities.** For those curious on further generalizations of Ramanujan's 6-10-8, while *Theorem 3* used $2^3$ terms, one with higher powers uses $2^5$ terms. Define,

$$\small P_n = \sum^{16}\, (\mu(a_1\pm a_2\pm a_3\pm a_4\pm a_5))^n - \sum^{16}\, (\mu(b_1\pm b_2\pm b_3\pm b_4\pm b_5))^n\tag1$$

where $\mu = \pm1$ and is the product of the interior signs. If ***four*** conditions are now satisfied,

$$\small\prod^5 a_i = \prod^5 b_i$$

$$\small \sum^5 a_i^k = \sum^5 b_i^k$$

for $k = 2,4,6$, then,

$$P_1 = P_2 = P_3 = P_4 = P_5 = P_6 = P_7 = P_9 = P_{11} = 0$$

and,

$$957\,P_8 P_{15} = 1547\,P_{10} P_{13}$$

**II. Families.** I found one can solve the four conditions in two ways: the first in terms of *quadratic forms*, and the second as an *elliptic curve*.

**Family 1:** If $x^2+21y^2 = z^2$, then,

$$a_i = x + 6 y,\; x + 5 y - z,\; x + 5 y + z,\; \tfrac{1}{2}(-5x+2y),\; \tfrac{3}{2}(x-6y)$$

$$b_i = x - 6 y,\; -x + 5 y - z,\; -x + 5 y + z,\; \tfrac{1}{2}(5x+2y),\; \tfrac{3}{2}(x+6y)$$

**Family 2:** If $-4a^2+5b^2=4c^2,\;\; 25a^2+24b^2=d^2$, then,

$$a_i = 4 a - 4 b,\; 3 b - 2 c,\; 3 b + 2 c,\; 6 a,\; 4 a + 4 b$$

$$b_i = b - 2 c,\; b + 2 c,\; 4 a,\; -a + d,\; a + d$$

*Note:* For the second family, eight terms will cancel out in $(1)$, so it really involves only $2^5-8=24$ terms. An initial solution is $a,b,c,d = 29, 26, 2, 193$ and, using an elliptic curve, one can get an infinite more. Explicitly,

$$\small( 281, -207, -199, -107, \color{blue}{-61}, 125, \color{blue}{33}, -13, \color{blue}{25}, -21, \color{blue}{-113}, 49, 95, 187, 195, -269)^n=\\
\small(277, -247, -161, \color{blue}{-113}, -55, 131, 83, \color{blue}{25}, -3, \color{blue}{-61}, -109, \color{blue}{33}, 91, 139, 225, -255)^n$$

for $n = 1,2,3,4,5,7,9,11$. (The second family was found in 2013 with the help of *Roger Glendenning* who provided numerical solutions. After some trial and error, I found the form above.)

Answer (score 3):

How Ramanujan found the identity is, of course, a mystery, but with the intelligent use of a computer algebra system, many such identities can be found. I wrote an [article](http://www.math.grinnell.edu/~chamberl/papers/ramanujan_6_8_10.pdf) about this. Two of the simpler identities that were not listed above include
$$
F_{-2}F_3^2 = -3 F_{-1}^2 F_6
$$
and
$$
245F_3 F_{11} + 330F_7^2 = 539F_5 F_9 
$$

Answer (score 1):

I found that Theorem 4 and Theorem 5 can be simplified as below,

**Theorem 4(s)**:

Define $R_n = (x_1^n+x_2^n+x_3^n-y_1^n-y_2^n-y_3^n)/n,\;$ and $m = (\sum x_i^2)/(\sum x_i)^2$ .

If $R_1=R_2=0$, then 
$$2R_3R_5 = (m+1)R_4^2$$

**Theorem 5(s)**:

Define $R_n = (x_1^n+x_2^n+x_3^n+x_4^n-y_1^n-y_2^n-y_3^n-y_4^n)/n,\;$ and $m = (\sum x_i^2)/(\sum x_i)^2$ .

If $R_1=R_2=R_3=0$, then 
$$2R_4R_6 = (m+1)R_5^2$$

Futhermore, we have

Define $R_n = (x_1^n+x_2^n+x_3^n+x_4^n+x_5^n-y_1^n-y_2^n-y_3^n-y_4^n-y_5^n)/n,\;$ and $m = (\sum x_i^2)/(\sum x_i)^2$ .

If $R_1=R_2=R_3=R_4=0$, then 
$$2R_5R_7 = (m+1)R_6^2$$
and so on.

More similar identities can be found on my website on [Algebraic Identities](http://eslpower.org/Identity.htm).